# passing argument to \includegraphics inside \foreach loop

Tags: beamer, graphics, loops

I am trying to define a loop to create 4 of my slides in a Beamer presentation. Each slide will have a figure. A minimal example is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{xstring}
% This works both with inline lists and with macros containing lists
\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,\par}%

\begin{document}

\def\views{isometric,side,front,back}

\foreach \view [count=\n] in \views
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{MY TITLE 1}
    \framesubtitle{My subtitle 1}
    n = \n (works)
    \def\filename{\GetListMember{\views}{\n}}
    Filename = \filename (works)
    This doesn't work:
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\filename}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MY TITLE 2}
  \framesubtitle{My subtitle 2}
  This works:
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{isometric}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why the \includegraphics inside the loop doesn't work, whereas the one outside the loop does. The error I am getting is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                                  {#1}
l.27 }
```

Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Why don't you directly use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\view}`?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but the `\centering` is unnecessary, beamer will automatically centre the figure. If your tex distribution isn't completely outdated, you also don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that has been the default for a couple of years now.

Comment: `\StrBetween` is protected; it can only be printed, not used.  To put the string into a macro , use `\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,[\filename]}`  Then again, you really don't need it.

Comment: xstring functions are notoriously unexpandable and will not work in any expansion context, you need somthing that expands to a filename, you can not do `\includegraphics{\def\tmp{file}\tmp}` which is what xstring is doing (with many internal definitions) but here you don't need it at all you can just use `\view` (or if you do need substring latex has expandable functions built in.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. You are right: using `\view` works. Thanks also for the feedback about `\centering` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple. The filename is readily available via `\view`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \view in {example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c}{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{MY TITLE 1}
    \framesubtitle{My subtitle 1}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\view}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @RigelF.doC. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The items in a `listofitems` list, once read, are fully expandable.  List loops are provided by the package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\views{example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c}
\readlist*\filenames{\views}
\foreachitem \view \in \filenames[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{MY TITLE 1}
    \framesubtitle{My subtitle \viewcnt}
    n = \viewcnt{}
    Filename = \view
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\view}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!